# Custom listview is not showing and getView is not called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have problem that my list view is not showing and the `getView` method never invoked

here is my list view inside the `onCreate` in the `MainActivity`

```
l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvv);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, maainimg);

        l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listvv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="#b4be"
       android:dividerHeight="2dp"></ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/BottomBanner">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my `CustomAdapter` Class it is inside the `MainActivity`

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        int[] img;
        Activity activity;
        ImageButton imageButton;
        public CustomAdapter(Activity act, int [] images) {
            super(act, R.layout.custom_row);
            this.activity=act;
            this.img=images;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d("getView","Called!");

            View row = convertView;
            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

                imageButton   = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.preview);}

            imageButton.setImageResource(img[position]);
            Log.d("added",position+"");
            if (getSelectedcolor() == 0) {
                imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                setSelectedcolor(Color.RED);

            } else {
                imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colorToHexString(getSelectedcolor())));

            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

and the **custom_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_1_red"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update** 
here is my array maainimg its not empty

```
 maainimg = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_1_red,R.drawable.ic_2_red,R.drawable.ic_3_red,R.drawable.ic_4_red,R.drawable.ic_5_red,R.drawable.ic_6_red,
                R.drawable.ic_7,R.drawable.ic_8,R.drawable.ic_8,R.drawable.ic_9,R.drawable.ic_10,R.drawable.ic_11,R.drawable.ic_12
                ,R.drawable.ic_13,R.drawable.ic_14,R.drawable.ic_15,R.drawable.ic_16,R.drawable.ic_17,R.drawable.ic_18,R.drawable.ic_19,R.drawable.ic_20,
                R.drawable.ic_21,R.drawable.ic_22,R.drawable.ic_23,R.drawable.ic_24,R.drawable.ic_25};
```

Comment: I think your array of image resource ids is empty,(maainimg)

Comment: Are you sure that you have some data in `maainimg`?

Comment: Unrelated but put `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` outside of getView, that's a slow operation compared to the rest.

Comment: @Diyoda no it's not empty check the update

Comment: @Rami no it's not check the update

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is your Layout.

```
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listvv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:divider="#b4be"
       android:dividerHeight="2dp"></ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Your `ListView` has no room left because the bottom linear layout is using `FILL_PARENT` (*which is deprecated btw, use `MATCH_PARENT` instead*).

Try making your ListView height (and width) to be both `MATCH_PARENT`. And then deal with the "Ad".

You could have the `LinearLayout` replaced by a `RelativeLayout` and have the Ad pin at the bottom of its parent and below the listview.

Second: Why are you using an `ArrayAdapter<String>` if you're internally using an array of `int`.

Third: since you're using the *wrong type of adapter*, you're not correctly implementing it, you need to override more methods (`getCount()` for example), to tell the underlying adapter: hey, this is the number of items we have.

Since you're not using the *provided* array of strings, but your custom array of ints that you pass during construction, try overriding getCount() and return the size of your int array instead.

Answer (score 1):

I this there is a issue in your Adapter class, Try this, But keep in mind that there are cleaner ways of writing this same code,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
        int[] img;
        Context context;
        ImageButton imageButton;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, Integer [] images) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_row, images);
            this.context=context;
            this.img=images;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d("getView","Called!");

            View row = convertView;
            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

            }

            imageButton   = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.preview);
            imageButton.setImageResource(img[position]);
            Log.d("added",position+"");
            if (getSelectedcolor() == 0) {
                imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                setSelectedcolor(Color.RED);

            } else {
                imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colorToHexString(getSelectedcolor())));

            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While you call `super(act, R.layout.custom_row);` (without passing the objects), you need to override [`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount()) method, otherwise your adapter can't figure out how many items you have, and this is why there is no call of `getView()` method.

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
   return img.length;
}
```